# Combine the SUM of a SELECT subquery and join the rows that have NULLS

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, left-join, aggregate-functions

I am running a query that pulls invoicing information from a database using a group by query to sum up four different line items and group them by month. The query involves 3 tables in a `JOIN`: `CustomerAccount`, `Invoice`, and `InvoiceDetail`. When I perform the query I get the correct information, however it is split across four rows with each column having one value while the rest are `NULL`. How do I combine the rows such that they all display on one row?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
    [Client].[CustID] AS [Account#],
    [Client].[Branch] AS [Branch],
    [Client].[Dept] AS [Department],
    CONCAT(DATEPART(YEAR, [dbo].[Invoice].[Date]), '-', RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2), DATEPART(MONTH, [dbo].[Invoice].[Date])), 2) ) AS [Date],
    [Client].[Name],
    (SELECT FORMAT(SUM([InvDetail].[SubTotal]), 'C', 'en-us') WHERE [InvDetail].[Description] = 'Delivery/Pickup') AS [Dlvry],
    (SELECT FORMAT(SUM([InvDetail].[SubTotal]), 'C', 'en-us') WHERE [InvDetail].[Description] = 'File Storage') AS [Storage],
    (SELECT FORMAT(SUM([InvDetail].[SubTotal]), 'C', 'en-us') WHERE [InvDetail].[Description] = 'BOX RETRIEVAL' OR [InvDetail].[Description] = 'BOX RETFILE') AS [Ret/Ref],
    (SELECT FORMAT(SUM([InvDetail].[SubTotal]), 'C', 'en-us') WHERE [InvDetail].[Description] LIKE 'Shredding%') AS [Shredding],
    FORMAT(SUM([InvDetail].[SubTotal]), 'C', 'en-us') AS [SubTotal],
    FORMAT(SUM([InvDetail].[GST]), 'C', 'en-us') AS [GST],
    FORMAT(SUM([InvDetail].[PST]), 'C', 'en-us') AS [PST],
    FORMAT(SUM([InvDetail].[Total]), 'C', 'en-us') AS [Total]
FROM [dbo].[CustomerAccount] AS [Client] LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Invoice]
    ON [Client].[CustID] = [dbo].[Invoice].[CustID]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[InvoiceDetail] AS [InvDetail]
    ON [dbo].[Invoice].[InvoiceNumber] = [InvDetail].[InvoiceNumber]

WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, [dbo].[Invoice].[Date]) >= 2015
      AND DATEPART(YEAR, [dbo].[Invoice].[Date]) <= 2017
      AND [Acct] = @ACCOUNT#
      AND [Branch] = @BRANCH
      AND [Dept] = @DEPARTMENT
GROUP BY [Client].[CustID], 
         [Client].[Branch], 
         [Client].[Dept], 
         [Client].[Name],
         DATEPART(YEAR, [dbo].[Invoice].[Date]),
         DATEPART(MONTH, [dbo].[Invoice].[Date]),
         [InvDetail].[Description]

ORDER BY [Client].[CustID]
```

The query result looks like this:

```
| Account# | Branch | Department | Date    | Name | Delvry | Storage | Ret/Ref | Shredding
| 1000     | MAIN   | TAX        | 2016-01 | Acme | $50.00 | NULL    | NULL    | NULL
| 1000     | MAIN   | TAX        | 2016-01 | Acme | NULL   | $200.00 | NULL    | NULL
| 1000     | MAIN   | TAX        | 2016-01 | Acme | NULL   | NULL    | $124.00 | NULL
| 1000     | MAIN   | TAX        | 2016-01 | Acme | NULL   | NULL    | NULL    | $12.75
```

I want it to look like this:

```
| Account# | Branch | Department | Date    | Name | Delvry | Storage | Ret/Ref | Shredding
| 1000     | MAIN   | TAX        | 2016-01 | Acme | $50.00 | $200.00 | $124.00 | $12.75
```

I'm at a loss as to how to proceed.

Comment: the query result that you posted does not matches your query. Please update

Comment: remove `[dbo].[InvoiceDetail].[Description]` from the GROUP BY

Comment: One recommend: plz use [Alias for Tables](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the query result that you are getting, you stored in a table named IntermediateTable. The query to get the required result will be:

```
SELECT Account# 
       ,Branch
       ,Department
       ,Date
       ,Name
       ,SUM(ISNULL(Delvry,0))
       ,SUM(ISNULL(Storage,0))
       ,SUM(ISNULL(Ret/Ref,0))
       ,SUM(ISNULL(Shredding,0))
FROM IntermediateTable
GROUP BY Account# 
       ,Branch
       ,Department
       ,Date
       ,Name
```